# Matching legend labels and colour to the pie plot segment colours in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I can successfully render two shiny pie plots by calling a plot function twice. When the plot  function is called, it passes the parameter values to ggplot specific to plot1 and plot2  repectively. This means the code for ggplot only needs to be written once.

A checkbox widget allows  the user to tick any combination of dates and the plots successfully update. The %'s in the pies  are 100% correct.

**The problem is the colours in the legend labels don't line up with the segment  colours in the Pie**.

For example, the legend label, "01 Months" is yellow and the yellow segment in  the Pie says 25%. But 25% should be the "06 Months" segment. The legend label, "06 Months" is Orange  and the orange segment in the Pie says 19%. But 19% should be the "Over a year" segment"..and so on  with the remaining 4 segments, a mismatch with the Pie segment colours.

Interestingly, this is not a  problem if the code for ggplot is written separately for plot1 and plot2. It is only a problem when  ggplot is wrapped inside a function and called.

I haven't been able to find a similar issue in stack  overflow so was hoping that someone could help me on this. I have included the full ui and server  code + libraries + a sample data.frame for this exercise. There must be some way to associate the  legend labels with the the correct colours to tie in with the pie segment colours.

The legend labels  come from the age_group variable for plot1 and the Outcome variable for plot2. I have defined 6  colours for the 6 levels of age_group and 4 colours for the 4 levels of Outcome.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# use the below if you want to increase the file size being inputed to 9MB
# options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9.1024^2)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Example",

                   tabPanel("Data",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(
                                "Nothing here at the moment"),
                              mainPanel("Select Dashboard Panel for results.Click on Select/All to make the plots 
          render"))
                   ),

                   tabPanel("Dashboard",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(
                                checkboxInput('all', 'Select All/None', value = TRUE),
                                uiOutput("year_month"),
                                tags$head(tags$style("#year_month{color:red; font-size:12px; font-style:italic; 
                   overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 100px; background: ghostwhite;}"))),
                              mainPanel( 
                                uiOutput("tb")))
                   )
))    

complaint_id <- 
  c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
    31,32,33)
age_group <- c("Over a year", "06 Months", "01 Months", "Over a year", "06 Months", "09 Months",
               "01 Months", "03 Months", "06 Months", "03 Months", "12 Months", "09 Months",
               "01 Months", "06 Months", "01 Months", "12 Months", "01 Months", "09 Months",
               "06 Months", "09 Months", "Over a year", "Over a year", "01 Months", "12 Months",
               "06 Months", "01 Months", "09 Months", "12 Months", "03 Months", "01 Months",
               "Over a year", "01 Months", "01 Months")
closed_date_ym <- c("2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-08", "2019-08", "2019-08", "2019-08", "2019-09",
                    "2018-08", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-09", "2019-09", "2019-08", "2019-08",
                    "2019-09", "2019-09", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-09", "2019-09", "2019-09",
                    "2019-09", "2019-09", "2019-09", "2019-08", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-08",
                    "2019-08", "2019-08", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-09"
)
officer <- c("E", "D", "B", "A", "A", "D", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "B", "C", "D", "A", "A", 
             "D",
             "A", "E", "C", "B", "C", "E", "E", "E", "A", "A", "A", "B", "E", "C", "D", "B")

Outcome <- c("Excellent", "Poor", "OK", "Excellent", "Poor", "Good", "Poor", "Good", "Poor", 
             "Excellent",
             "Poor", "Good", "Excellent", "Good", "Poor", "Poor", "Excellent", "Poor", "Poor", "Good",
             "OK", "OK", "Excellent", "Poor", "Good", "OK", "Good", "OK", "Good", "Excellent",
             "Excellent", "Excellent", "Excellent")

sample_data <- data.frame(complaint_id, age_group, closed_date_ym, officer, Outcome)

server <- shinyServer(function(session, input, output){

  # Make it reactive
  data <- reactive({
    sample_data
  })

  # Have to modify the reactive data object to add a column of 1s(Ones) inorder
  # that the Pie chart %s are calculated correctly within the segments. We apply
  # this modification to a new reactive object, data_mod()
  data_mod <- reactive({
    req(data())
    data_mod <-
      data() %>% select(complaint_id, age_group, closed_date_ym, officer, Outcome)
    data_mod$Ones <- rep(1, nrow(data()))
    data_mod
  })


  # creates a selectInput widget with unique YYYY-MM variables ordered from most
  # recent to oldest time period

  output$year_month <- renderUI({
    req(data_mod())
    data_ordered <-
      order(data_mod()$closed_date_ym, decreasing = TRUE)
    data_ordered <- data_mod()[data_ordered,]
    checkboxGroupInput("variable_month",
                       "Select Month",
                       choices = unique(data_ordered$closed_date_ym))

  })

  observe({
    req(data_mod())
    data_ordered <-
      order(data_mod()$closed_date_ym, decreasing = TRUE)
    data_ordered <- data_mod()[data_ordered,]
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session,
      "variable_month",
      choices = unique(data_ordered$closed_date_ym),
      selected = if (input$all)
        unique(data_ordered$closed_date_ym)
    )

  })
  # This subsets the dataset based on what "variable month" above is selected
  # and renders it into a Table
  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(data_mod())
    dftable <- data_mod()
    df_subset <- dftable[, 1:5][dftable$closed_date_ym %in%
                                  input$variable_month, ]
  },
  options = list(scrollX = TRUE))

  # This takes the modified reactive data object data_mod(), assigns it to a
  # dataframe df. The dataset in df is subsetted based on the selected variable
  # month above and assigned into a new data frame, DF. The Pie chart is
  # built on the variables within DF

  plot_func <- function(DF, grp_vars, title, scale) {
    group_by(DF, DF[[grp_vars]]) %>%
      summarize(volume = sum(Ones)) %>%
      mutate(share = volume / sum(volume) * 100.0) %>%
      arrange(desc(volume)) %>%
      ggplot(aes("", share, fill = unique(DF[[grp_vars]]))) +
      geom_bar(
        width = 1,
        size = 1,
        color = "white",
        stat = "identity"
      ) +
      coord_polar("y") +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(share), "%")),#share,digits=2
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
      labs(
        x = NULL,
        y = NULL,
        fill = NULL,
        title = title
      ) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = scale) +

      theme_classic() +
      theme(
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666")
      )
  }
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(data_mod(), input$variable_month)
    plot_func(
      DF = data_mod()[, 1:6][data_mod()$closed_date_ym %in% input$variable_month, ],
      grp_vars = "age_group",
      title = "Age Group Segmentation",
      scale = c(
        "#ffd700",
        "#bcbcbc",
        "#ffa500",
        "#254290",
        "#f0e68c",
        "#808000"
      )
    )
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    req(data_mod(), input$variable_month)
    plot_func(
      DF = data_mod()[, 1:6][data_mod()$closed_date_ym %in% input$variable_month, ],
      grp_vars = "Outcome",
      title = "Outcome Segmentation",
      scale = c("#ffd700", "#bcbcbc", "#ffa500", "#254290")
    )
  })

  # the following renderUI is used to dynamically gnerate the tabsets when the file is loaded
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Plot",
                         plotOutput("plot1"), plotOutput("plot2")),
                tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: See the "minimal" part in [mcve] and make sure that if the question is actually related to Shiny, that this is a Shiny app folks will be able to run easily

Comment: Yes, this can be run as is, just copy into into a ui.r and server.r file as is and run app in RStudio.

Comment: I updated the code, so it can be run in a single file "app.R", which is more common on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the use of `unique` for `fill` in `ggplot`. The `fill` group needs to correspond to `share` which you are plotting.

If you use `browser()` you can see what is happening in `plot_func`. Before you call `ggplot`, this is what you have for `plotdf` (temporary variable created):

```
plotdf <- group_by(DF, DF[[grp_vars]]) %>%
  summarize(volume = sum(Ones)) %>%
  mutate(share = volume / sum(volume) * 100.0) %>%
  arrange(desc(volume)) 

browser()

  `DF[[grp_vars]]` volume share
  <fct>             <dbl> <dbl>
1 01 Months             5 29.4 
2 09 Months             4 23.5 
3 12 Months             3 17.6 
4 06 Months             2 11.8 
5 Over a year           2 11.8 
6 03 Months             1  5.88
```

Notice each of the `DF[[grp_vars]]` with `share` will be different than what you get with `unique` here (a different order):

```
Browse[1]> unique(DF[[grp_vars]])
[1] 06 Months   01 Months   03 Months   12 Months   09 Months   Over a year
Levels: 01 Months 03 Months 06 Months 09 Months 12 Months Over a year
```

If you keep `plotdf` you can get the correct charts by using both `share` and `DF[[grp_vars]]` in `plotdf`:

```
plotdf %>%
  ggplot(aes("", share, fill = `DF[[grp_vars]]`))
```

[image: pie chart with legend]

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me that insight into pie chart segmentation with R code. I applied your above code modification to my main imported data file and the problem is now fixed.